# noSuchMethod error in android

Tags: android, runtime-error, nosuchmethoderror

I use fragments:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
```

but I see this error in log cat:

```
12-30 21:14:05.500: E/AndroidRuntime(395): 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:my.com.daily.Sign_upActivity.getFragmentManager
```

and my activity is:

```
public class sign_upActivity extends Activity implements AlertPositiveListener{

public String fonts="BZar.ttf";
private EditText fname,lname,birthdate,worktitle,company,username,pass,confpass,email,phone,phone1;
private Button signup;
private String gender;
private String education ,regiterDate,howIMF,expdate,active,picpath,deleted , expertise;
private RadioGroup radioGenderGroup;
private RadioButton radioGenderButton;
private Drawable error_indicator;
int position = 0;
int position1 = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
            Bundle b  = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", position);
            alert.setArguments(b);
            alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");

        }
    };      

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.education_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void onPositiveClick(int position) {
    this.position = position;
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.education_tv);
    tv1.setText(Education.code[this.position]); 
    education = Education.code[this.position];
}
```

}

can anyone tell me what is the reason?

thanks alot .my problem solved in emulator but it force close in phone! I use minSdkVersion="4"

Comment: Do you run on a device before API Level 11?

Answer (score 1):

[FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) is only from api level 11. My guess you are deploying on an older device which doesnt support this.

Look at the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are using a minimum API below version 11. Fragments were add in API 11, but they are available through the Support Library down to API 4. However there are a few differences, for instance you must extend FragmentActivity to get access to the FragmentManager:

```
public class sign_upActivity extends FragmentActivity ...
```

Another difference is that you must use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

You are using api lesser than 11. Due to these you're getting error. FragmentManaget.getFragmentManger(); method is not supported in before Api level 11.

Also getFragmentManager() method is not added on

#### Compatibility Library